# Manipulating and tracking integers of a loop in C

Tags: c, loops, do-while

so I'm fairly new to C and programming in general and also new to the website.  Looking for guidance/help on figuring it all out, including help on how to properly use and ask questions on here.

So what I wanted to figure out is how to keep track of user defined numbers entered and also the value of the numbers added together.  I was playing around with it for awhile looking for solutions, i was thinking there is a problem with my ways of keeping a count and not so much, there are no errors or warnings but the compiler stops after asking for an integer.

Any help or advice is much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 int main()
 {
int num, sumodd, sumeven, countodd, counteven;
char name;
printf("Please enter your name. \n");
scanf("%c", &name);
printf("Please enter an integer. \n");
do {
    scanf("%d", &num);
    if (num%2 == 0)
        sumeven = sumeven + num;
        counteven = counteven + num++;
    if (num%2 == 1)
        sumodd = sumodd + num;
        countodd = countodd + num++;
} while (num > 0);
printf("%c, the numbers you entered are broken down as follows: \n", name);
printf("You entered %d even numbers with a value totaling at %d", counteven, sumeven);
printf("You entered %d odd numbers with a value totaling at %d", countodd, sumodd);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't be adding `num++` to `counteven` or `countodd` just add 1.  `counteven++;`, `counteven += 1;` or `counteven = counteven + 1;` will do.

Comment: `scanf("%c", &name);` - I think you are expecting a name would be more than one character. Perhaps read the manual page for `scanf` and use `char name[200];` then `fgets`

Comment: put blocks of code after `if` in `{}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in comments you were doing some mistakes like:

- Not initializing `sumodd, sumeven, countodd, counteven` to zero
- Not using `{ }` in `if else` blocks of odd even checking
- Using a character for a `name` variable
- adding `num++` to count variables instead of 1, and thereby changing its value.

I modified your code slightly :

```
  int num, sumodd = 0, sumeven = 0, countodd = 0, counteven = 0; // initialize to zero
  char name[200];
  printf("Please enter your name. \n");
  scanf("%s", name);
  printf("Please enter an integer. \n");
  do {
      scanf("%d", &num);
      if (num%2 == 0) {
          sumeven = sumeven + num;
          counteven = counteven + 1;
      }
      if (num%2 == 1) {
          sumodd = sumodd + num;
          countodd = countodd + 1;
      }
  } while (num > 0);
  printf("%s, the numbers you entered are broken down as follows: \n", name);
  printf("You entered %d even numbers with a value totaling at %d\n", counteven, sumeven);
  printf("You entered %d odd numbers with a value totaling at %d\n", countodd, sumodd);
```

When i ran it i was able to see desired output:

```
~/Documents/src : $ ./a.out 
Please enter your name. 
Rohan
Please enter an integer. 
1
2
3
0
Rohan, the numbers you entered are broken down as follows: 
You entered 2 even numbers with a value totaling at 2
You entered 2 odd numbers with a value totaling at 4
```

Comment: Thank you so very much, this response was extremely clear and insightful. Cheers